# Nuxt method call another method : Promise is not a function

Tags: javascript, filter, nuxt.js

On nuxt.js (vue.js), i have to make a function filtering a JSON.
This JSON contain couples of persons:

```
couple: [
  {
     id: 1,
     pers1: {
       id: 1,
       firstname: 'Vincent',
     },
     pers2: {
       id: 1,
        firstname: 'Leslie',
     },
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     pers1: {
       id: 3,
       firstname: 'Leslie',
     },
     pers2: {
       id: 4,
       firstname: 'Henri',
     },
  },
]
```

There is a form to allow user making a search on the firstname of person.
If he searchs "Leslie", the result must be:

- Vincent & Leslie
- Leslie & Henri

If he search "Henri", the result must be:

- Leslie & Henri

I wrote:

```
  methods:{
     async searchCouple() {
        this.filterCouples.filter(this.makeFilter(this.firstname));
     },
     async makeFilter(search){
        return function(element){
           return element.couple.pers1.firstname.toUpperCase() === search || element.couple.pers2.firstname.toUpperCase() === search;
        }
     }
```

But i have this error:

```
TypeError: #<Promise> is not a function
```

If i write:

```
async searchCouple() {
   this.filterCouples = this.couple.filter(a => a.pers1.firstname.toUpperCase() === this.firstname.toUpperCase());
}
```

It's ok (but only on ONE personn). But if i write:

```
async searchCouple() {
   this.filterCouples = this.couple.filter(a => a.pers1.firstname.toUpperCase() === this.firstname.toUpperCase() || a.pers2.firstname.toUpperCase() === this.firstname.toUpperCase());
}
```

Boom :( .

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT :**

I change my code with :

```
methods: {
   async searchCouple() {
      this.filterCouple.filter(this.makeFilter(this.firstname));
   },
    makeFilter(search){
        return function(element){
             if(element.pers1.firstname.toUpperCase() == search.toUpperCase()
        || element.pers2.firstname.toUpperCase() == search.toUpperCase()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My function return good values (console.log):

```
Vincent IN Vincent / Leslie = true
Vincent IN Leslie / Henri = false
```

Or :

```
Leslie IN Vincent / Leslie = true
Leslie IN Leslie / Henri = true
```

BUT : filterCouple return ALL my json, despite the result of the function :(

Comment: an `async` function will always return a Promise. Both your functions don't need to be marked as `async`, so removing that should resolve your error

Comment: @NickParsons thanks, it was that.
Now i write : this.filterCouples.filter(this.makeFilter(this.firstname));
But : my function makeFilter return true or false (correctly), but this.filterCouples still return ALL my JSON.

Comment: The filter method returns a new array, it doesn’t change the array that the filter method is called on. You can store the result in a new variable (advised) or re-assign the return value back to filterCouples

Comment: @NickParsons: i love you ;) ;) ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NickParsons: maybe a Bonus question for you: i have to make the same search on the lastname. I want to keep only 1 function. So i used a second param and wrote : this.filterCouples.filter(this.makeFilter(this.firstname), 'firstname'); In my function : makeFilter(search, node){ ... }, how i can use the node param ? Ex : element.pers1.{{node}} == ... ?

Comment: it was just : element.pers1[node].